# How to rethrown an exception in Java

Tags: java, spring, exception, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I am using maven codegen plugin to generate the controller interface with a schema like the following

```
    responses:
        '200':
            content:
                application/json:
                    schema:
                        $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyResponse'
            description: OK
        '401':
            content:
                application/json:
                    schema:
                        $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyError'
```

The interface like the following

```
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Authentication succeeded", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = MyResponse.class))),
        
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Authentication failed", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = MyError.class))) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default ResponseEntity<MyResponse> LoginMethod(//some parameters...) { //something}
```

In my controller, I would like to call an external API which throws an API exception

```
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> LoginMethod(//some parameters...) {
try { 
  //call external API which throw an exception 
} catch(ApiException e){
  e.getResponseBody; // This is a string type of MyError class in JSON format returned
  // throw e;
}
```

I would like to redirect the response body but the interface defines the return type to be ResponseEntity so I can't simply rethrow the exception or return  ResponseEntity.

@ApiResponse seems not correcting the response type as well.

As stated in this question,
[How to handle multiple response/return types (empty for 204, non-empty for 400 etc) in swagger codegen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325210/how-to-handle-multiple-response-return-types-empty-for-204-non-empty-for-400-e)

I can throw as this way

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.valueOf(e.getCode()), e.getResponseBody());
```

But is there a better way to do that? I just want to return the e.getResponseBody() as an object instead of a string.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `ApiException` in throws declaration like that :

```java
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> LoginMethod(//some parameters...) throws ApiException {
   // here your code that can create teh ApiException
}
```

Now the method which call this will ask for the throw exception too. You will be able to manage exception in it.

You can also create a new object which contains all informations that you need. It will also format informations to be always the same, not depending of the throwed error.

Comment: It doesn't work as stated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754684/overridden-method-does-not-throw-exception. And I can't modify the interface as I am using the codegen plugin.

Comment: Oh ok, you seems too limited to do what you are looking for, except if you can create a responseEntity that correspond to an error. I know that other API enable like `Response.CreateErrorResponse()`

Comment: Do you think I can write a Exception handler to handle this? But I looking for a simple solution if possible